# Як правильно перекласти "Default value"?

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-english

Я часто перекладаю *"default value"* як  *"типове значення"*. На мою думку це звучить краще ніж досить поширене *"значення за замовчуванням"*. Хоча, можливо, не є дуже точним.

Які варіанти є грамотним перекладом з точки зору практичного вживання в галузі інформаційних технологій?

Comment: А хіба не «значення за замовчуванням»? Це ж у кожному словнику є...

Comment: @YellowSky, Ви праві, це найтиповіший і «найнудніший» переклад (довгий, не прикметник, калька з російської). Йому весь час намагаються знайти альтернативу (хтось каже «типовий», он [Пономарів взагалі «усталений/заданий» пропонує](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/05/150512_ponomariv_blog55_ko) тощо). Але, наскільки я знаю, *загальноприйнятої* альтернативи досі не знайшли.

Comment: Всі германські мови вживають «стандартне значення», мови колишьої Югославії «задане значення», румунською «імпліцитне значення». Особисто я казав би «необговорене/необумовлене значення».

Comment: Ну так згаданий вами Пономарів і пропонує «задане значення».

Comment: @YellowSky Це калька з російської, єдине значення слова в українській слова замовчувати - це не казати щось, мовчати про щось.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Я пропоную зробити wiki-відповідь (для спільного редагування), де перерахувати всі наявні варіанти в алфавітному порядку з їхніми джерелами, перевагами і недоліками. Почну сам…

- **Задане** значення<sup>П</sup>.

  Недоліки:

  - Ким задане? «Задане виробником (чи розробником)» — це default. «Задане користувачем» — те, яке він встановив, антонім до default. «Задане» (без уточнень) — не зовсім однозначно.
- Значення **за замовчуванням**<sup>MS</sup>.

  Недоліки:

  - Не є прикметником.
  - Довге.
  - Калька з російської.
- Значення **за промовчуванням**<sup>MS</sup> (а також **за промовчанням**<sup>MS</sup>).

  Недоліки:

  - Не є прикметником.
  - Довге.
  - Калька з російської.
  - Слова «промовчання» в словниках немає.
- **Стандартне** значення<sup>MS</sup>.

  Недоліки:

  - Одне зі значень слова [стандартний](http://sum.in.ua/s/standartnyj) — «за поширеним зразком». У випадку невдалого (для широкого загалу чи для певної авдиторії) default-значення поширеним серед користувачів зразком налаштувань може стати не-default. В такому випадку слово «стандартне» набуває двозначності: «стандартне» в значенні «за виробником/розробником» і «стандартне» в значенні «те, що зазвичай люди ставлять».
- **Типове** значення<sup>KDE, LOU</sup> (в т.ч. *типо́ве* значення<sup>LOU</sup> і *типове́* значення).

  Недоліки:

  - Слово [типо́вий](http://sum.in.ua/s/typovyj) має значення «який часто зустрічається, звичайним, природним». Default-значення і значення, що часто зустрічається — не завжди одне й те ж (якщо default-значення незручне для певної категорії користувачів і вони часто встановлюють собі інше значення, то для них типо́вим, тобто поширеним, відповідно, буде воно, а не default). Хоча, згідно з СУМ-11, слово типов́ий такого значення не має, але: по-перше, не всі навіть носії мови відрізняють такі відтінки за наголосом (наголос і його сприйняття може варіювати за діалектами);  по-друге, на письмі рідко ставлять наголос.
  - Слово *типове* перегукується із терміном *тип*, у значенні *«тип даних»*. В індустрії інформаційних технологій, будь-яка інформація має *тип*, як-то «ціле число», «раціональне число», «текст», «булеве» тощо. Бувають також складані *типи*, наприклад, *тип даних* «адреса» містить кілька «полей даних», як-то «місто», «вулиця», «поштовий індекс» тощо. Таким чином, *«типове значення»* може викликати непорозуміння.
- **Уста́вне** значення<sup>М&К</sup>.

  Недоліки:

  - Чи використовується на практиці десь?
  - Чи інтуїтивно зрозуміле значення слова (в парі з «значення», «налаштування» тощо) хоча б приблизно, якщо не знати його заздалегідь?
- **Усталене** значення<sup>П</sup>.

  Недоліки:

  - Аналогічно до «типовий» — default- та усталене значення не завжди збігаються. Якщо в певної аудиторії є певні потреби, що роблять для них найприйнятнішим якесь значення — то для них усталеним буде саме воно (навіть якщо воно не default-). «Усталене виробником (чи розробником)» — так, це саме default, але чи є слово «усталене» (без уточнень) однозначним?

<sub>Джерела: 

KDE — [Ukrainian KDE Localization](https://l10n.kde.org/team-infos.php?teamcode=uk), наприклад [dolphin.po](https://websvn.kde.org/*checkout*/branches/stable/l10n-kf5/uk/messages/applications/dolphin.po). 

LOU — [«Англійсько-український словник з ІТ», створений добровольцями, не виданий (1999–2011)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=default&dicts=3). 

М&К — [«Англійсько-український словник з математики та інформатики» Є. Мейнаровича та М. Кратка (2010)](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=default&dicts=2). 

MS — [Microsoft Language Portal Terminology Search](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Search.aspx?sString=default&langID=uk-ua). 

П — [думка мовознавця професора О. Пономаріва](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/05/150512_ponomariv_blog55_ko).</sub>

Comment: `Default value` по свої суті - це _наперед обране значення_ або ж _преобране значення_. Тому пропоную відштовхуватись також і від такого трактування цього словосполучення.

Comment: @BohdanKuts, "преобране значення" — мені подобається. Але в цій відповіді я аналізував варіанти, що **вже використовуються**. Створіть свою окрему відповідь (сподіваюся, її не замінусують як неаргументовану — принаймні, мені ця нова ідея дуже подобається, коротно і ясно) або додайте варіант в [паралельну дискусію на Словотворі](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/defoltnyi) (і [ще одна](http://slovotvir.org.ua/words/bai-defolt)).

Comment: Не відповідь, а ціла наукова праця. Скільки часу Вам знадобилося на її написання й пошуки джерел?

Comment: @AndrewBest, ну, джерела пошуку наявних відповідників у софті давно [тут](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/56/4). Хоча не всі вони вони такі зручні, як MS/KDE, тому треба певне терпіння, щоб у них щось знайти. Я хотів би колись потім зробити єдиний автоматизований інтерфейс пошуку для них усіх (типу, ввів «test» — і воно відразу показує переклади і з MS, і з KDE, і з Drupal, і з Gnome, і т.д.) — але не знаю, чи дійдуть колись руки. (А про думку Пономаріва я просто випадково чув раніше, знову загуглити її не проблема.)

Comment: @Sasha, дякую, не знав про ті джерела пошуку.

Comment: @Sasha Онлайн-коректор додали недавно переклад цього слова до своєї бази http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9/  та обгрунтування, можете додати у ваш пост.

Answer (score 10):

[Академічний тлумачний словник української мови](http://sum.in.ua/s/typovyj) подає прикметник тип**о**вий як:

> 1. Який відзначається ознаками, властивими якій-небудь сукупності осіб, явищ, предметів і т. ін. // Яскраво виражений, справжній.
> 2. Який часто зустрічається; характерний, звичайний, природний для кого-, чого-небудь.
> 3. Який виявляє загальне в частковому, індивідуальному.

і прикметник типов**и**й

> 1. Який є зразком, стандартом для ряду однорідних явищ, фактів.
> 2. Який відповідає певному типові, зразкові, зроблений за певним зразком, типом; стандартний.
> 3. Установлений, прийнятий для всіх установ, підприємств і т. ін. певного роду.

[Словник Мерріам-Вебстер](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/default) визначає прикметник default як:

> a:  a selection made usually automatically or without active consideration due to lack of a viable alternative
>
> b: computers :  a selection automatically used by a program in the absence of a choice made by the use

[Інший словник](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/default) дає наступні визначення 'default':

> adjective: A default situation is what exists or happens unless someone or something changes it.
>
> uncountable noun: In computing, the default is a particular set of instructions which the computer always uses unless the person using the computer gives other instructions.

по сенсу з пари тип**о**вий - типов**и**й, якщо і підходить, то другий варіант з наголосом на и, але мені видається у цього варіанта перекладу є очевидні недоліки:

1. Типово наголос або губиться на писмі, або перевантажує текст
2. Якщо не обумовлено інше, люди схильні читати 'типове', як 'тип**о**ве', а не 'типов**е**' як належить

Comment: Ця відповідь є правильною з точки зору словників, але є складною для практичного вживання, бо не завжди у інтерфейсі програмного забезпечення є можливість поставити наголос.

Answer (score 10):

В перекладі Drupal Українською ми зійшлись на ***базове значення***, тому що це відповідає суті бази, взятої за основу.

[Приклади словосполучень](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/uk/translate?project&status=0&release=all&search=%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5&author&context=all&limit=10&sid=0).

Comment: У Вас корисне джерело перекладів, я додав його в [список на ме́ті](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/56/4). До речі, [`так як`](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/43/4) вважається русизмом, рекомендую виправити (а якщо в Вас інша думка з цього приводу, то додати її в те питання).

Comment: Щодо Друпал як джерело перекладів
Направив всі запитання на даний ресурс звідтіля. Якщо бачитиме в тому джерелі помилки - будемо вдячні за виправлення.
Друпал переклад наразі перший серед усіх мов, а це не завжди було досягнуто якістю. З цим ми зараз намагаємось дати собі раду.

Answer (score 3):

Початкове значення
Значення за замовчуванням (часто зустрічаю цей варіант)

Comment: "Початкове значення" звучить дуже гарно. Інтуїтивно зрозуміло, про що йдеться і не є калькою з російської.

Comment: -1: ця відповідь не виглядає обґрунтованою. Спробуйте додати більше подробиць, пояснень та/або посилань.

Comment: Теж подобається цей варіант, але це швидше переклад _initial value_.

Comment: @EugeneFotin, а в чому різниця між default value й initial value?

Comment: @Sasha Initial - відноситься до положення в часі або просторі, і швидше за все до встановлення цього значення, значення було невизначене (пусте). Default - це зразкове конкретне значення, яке найкраще відповідає певному контексту. Звичайно, initial value може співпадати з default. Зручно пояснити псевдокодом (до речі, тому існують в деяких мовах uninitialised variables):
float pi; // нуль або сміття - initial value
pi = 3.14159; // default value, але у воєнний час може бути 3 або 4

Comment: @EugeneFotin, чесно — все ще не бачу різниці. По-моєму, default — це саме початкове в часі. Просто початкове можна брати в різному масштабі (наприклад, якщо якась змінна в модулі починає своє життя як невизначена чи 0, але встановлюється в 7 перед повертанням користувачу, то initial/default із точки зору розробника модуля — це unitinialized чи 0, а з точки зору користувача модуля — це 7).

Comment: @Sasha initial value - значення, яке присвоюється полю в конструкторі, тобто початкове, default value - значення, яке заноситься в поле під час зкидання стану обїекту до початкового. Це два початкових значення з ньюансами. Але в реальних задачах ці значення відрізняються доволі рідко. Згоден, що є відмінність. Інколи початковим вважають значення до того, як обїєкт був ініціалізований. Але це на мій погляд не вірно. Тому що сам термін не потрібний з технічної точки зору і якщо таке значення кортить якось назвати, то краще або невизначенне або нульове. Залежить від способу створення об'єкту.

Comment: @AlexSodin, просто, мені здається, що з логічної точки зору або в правильній системі (де нема такого, що «початкове» — одне, а «скидання до початкового» встановлює інше) це одне й те ж. Тому має сенс радше розглядати initial/default з різних позицій (initial/default з позиції розробника, initial/default з позиції кінцевого користувача, initial/default з позиції розробника плагінів) — аніж відрізняти initial і default, — але, може, я й неправий, хтозна.

Comment: Незмістовна і необгрунтована відповідь,-. Розгляньте варіант видалення цієї відповіді, оскілька більш змістовна відповідь вже присутня.

Answer (score 1):

**default** - дослівно означає [без впливу](https://www.lexico.com/definition/default)

**default value** - значення, на яке ще не вплинули

А отже **початкове значення** вважаю найвлучнішим варіантом для перекладу.