# By default українською

Tags: переклад, from-english

Дуже часто зустрічаю кальку з російської "за замовчуванням", але ж усім зрозуміло, що добре було б знайти кращий варіант перекладу. Пошукав тут - нічого не знайшов. Чи є в когось якісь думки з цього приводу?

Я шукаю саме обставину, що відповідала б на питання "як", а не прикметник. З [теми про "Default value"](/q/33) найбільш близьким здається слово *типо́во* або звичайне *зазвичай*.

Просто в англйській цей вираз чітко належить до лексики цифрової ери, а в українській, виходить, що не так - можна обійтися "старими" словами, без жодного натяку на діджиталізацію...

Comment: [«Як правильно перекласти „default value“?»](/q/33) — це часом не те, що Вам треба?

Comment: Цю тему я знайшов. Але що з неї виходить - `типо́во`? `Усталено`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Як правильно перекласти "Default value"?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/33/%d0%af%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-default-value)

Comment: @VitaliyTretyakov, немає єдиної думки (там наведено різні). Якщо Ви вважаєте, що в тому запитанні не розкритий якийсь аспект, то відредагуйте («edit»), будь ласка, це запитання, зазначивши, який саме аспект там не розкрито, тобто чому саме потрібне ще одне окреме запитання (наприклад, у тому запитанні мова була здебільшого про прикметники («який?»), а Вам потрібно щось, що виконуватиме роль обставини («як?»); або якийсь специфічний контекст уживання; будь-що, що відокремлюватиме це питання від того).

Comment: Я [б не сказав](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=by+default&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&smoothing=3), що «by default» належить суто до лексики цифрової ери.

Answer (score 6):

Якщо вас не влаштовує [ця відповідь](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/59/2097) - є [чудова стаття](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/) на [onlinecorrector](https://onlinecorrector.com.ua/), котра заснована на декількох джерелах та слугує гарним доповненням до вищезгаданої відповіді або повноцінною їй заміною, і котра, мені здається, відповідає на ваше питання.
 Скріншот статті нижче.

> [image: Скріншот]

**UPD:** Також недавно знайшов статтю ["Default: «по замовчуванню» чи «за налаштуванням»?"](http://science.lpnu.ua/terminology/all-volumes-and-issues/visnik-no-620-2008/default-po-zamovchuvannyu-chi-za) к.т.н., доц. Ігоря Кульчицького та к.ф-м.н., доц. Богдана Філя із Львівської Політехніки, де вони обґрунтовують чому вони вважають правильним переклад «за налаштуванням», але наскільки мені відомо, жодний із них не є лінгвістом, тому, на мою думку, той переклад не є авторитетним.

Answer (score 3):

**By default**

Щоб перекласти — потрібно зрозуміти значення. Щоб зрозуміти значення іноземного слова треба дослідити приклади використання та описи.

По перше ми маємо два слова для дослідження: *by* і *default*.

**By** — прийменник

[Перекладач](https://translate.google.com.ua/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=uk&text=by)

> Identifying the agent performing an action.

Тобто ким?, чим?.

**Default** — іменник (а є і дієслово і прикметник і бог зна що)

[Словник](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/by-default)

> If something happens by default, it happens only because something
>   else which might have prevented it or changed it has not happened.

Але ж треба розуміти, що наша мова відрізняється від англійської і не завжди можна віднайти слово замінник. Тому переходимо до випадків, де саме це слово нам потрібне.

Мова йде про *default value.* Звертаю увагу, що це переважно використовується в програмуванні. А в цій сфері переважна більшість значень — це абстрактні значення.
Отже, трохи розібралися зі значенням. Тримаємо попередні приклади-описи в голові і додаємо ще один приклад. Ускладнюємо становище.

**Default** — прикметник
**Value** — іменник

Прикметник, що означає “читаємо попередні приклади-пояснення англійською” і отримуємо “**заготовлене**”.

[Словник](http://sum.in.ua/s/zaghotovljaty)

> ЗАГОТОВЛЯТИ, яю, яєш і ЗАГОТОВЛЮВАТИ, юю, юєш, недок., ЗАГОТОВИТИ,
>   влю, виш; мн. заготовлять; і ЗАГОТУВАТИ, ую, уєш, док., перех.
>   Готувати, виготовляти що-небудь заздалегідь, до настання потреби,
>   наперед.

Тобто ми заготовили наперед значення для змінної і чекаємо на потребу використати за відсутності змін.

---

**Для тих, хто в темі.**

А давайте приклад, щоб зрозуміти.

У нас є комірка ax зі значенням 10. Ми заготовили це значення. Потім йдемо поступово далі по алгоритму і в результаті проходження усіх умов виявляється, що наша комірка не змінилася.

---

**Default value** — заготовлене значення.

Тепер перейдемо до "як?". Знову читаємо вище пояснення слова default в словнику і підбираємо схоже за значенням слово. Тобто таке значення, що було-було і якщо нічого не вплинуло, то і залишилося.
Як там кажуть: Спочатку було слово. Ні. Спочатку був великий вибух. Ну одним словом  "початково".

А тепер пограємося нашим новим визначенням, щоб закріпити та перевірити переклад.

Візьмемо якийсь програмістський сайт і перекладемо декілька речень з нашим словом.
Наприклад, “[site:www.phpdeveloper.org default](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=cIKXXb6FFoeqrgTwmoHABQ&q=site%3Awww.phpdeveloper.org%20default&oq=site%3Awww.phpdeveloper.org%20default&gs_l=psy-ab.3...986.986..1572...0.0..0.107.107.0j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.niRsZ2atcCM&ved=0ahUKEwi-_dvQkYPlAhUHlYsKHXBNAFgQ4dUDCAU&uact=5)”.

> “Rob Allen: Default route arguments in Slim”

- Роб Аллен: Заготовлені аргументи маршруту в "Стрункому".

> “Derek Allard's Blog: Modifying the default CodeIgniter Calendar
>   template for fun and profit”

- Блоґ Дерека Алларда: Зміна заготовленого шаблону календаря “Запальника Коду” для розваги й користі (та досвіду).

> “Matthias Noback: Final classes by default, why?”

- Матіас Нобак: Попередньо (початково, одразу) завершуйте класи, чому?

Як бачите - важливо зрозуміти значення слова, а не шукати якесь одне слово замінник. Можливо такого слова і не існує. Це все через різницю мов.

Також я показав приклад як я вирішую схожу проблему з перекладом та розумінням іноземної мови. Спробуйте піти тим самим шляхом. Можливо це допоможе.

Думаю, відповіддю на усі подібні питання будуть саме приклади використання та опис значень слів саме англійських джерел. Адже вони краще знають свою мову.

Comment: Щодо «Зміна заготовленого шаблону “Запальника Коду” для розваги та досвіду»… [CodeIgniter](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter) — це назва фреймворку, вона не перекладається. Загубили слово «Calendar». І, НЯМС, «profit»≠«досвід». Я б сказав: «Як змінити заготовлений шаблон календаря [в] CodeIgniter для розваги й [чи] користі».

Comment: "це назва фреймворку, вона не перекладається" - але ж я переклав ...

Comment: Я мав на увазі, що більшість людей (зокрема і я) вважають, що таке не треба перекладати. Більшість не каже «автівка „Народний візок“» (замість «автівка Volkswagen») чи «текстовий редактор „Слово“ від компанії „Мікром'який“» (замість «текстовий редактор Word від компанії Microsoft»).

Comment: Я вважаю інакше. Саме ці дрібниці заважають краще сприймати свою мову.

Comment: "«автівка „Народний візок“» (замість «автівка Volkswagen»)" - дякую, це доволі цікава інформація, яку я б можливо ніколи б так і не дізнався. Як саме перекладається назва автомобіля.

Comment: Ну, там насправді не так однозначно, Wagen (наскільки я розумію, я не знавець німецької) може позначати і автівку, і вагон, і вагонетку, і візок, і карету, і багато чого іншого (я так розумію, майже будь-що, що пересувається). Зазвичай, наприклад, [в українській вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkswagen), у ролі буквального перекладу наводять доречніше словосполучення — «народний автомобіль». (Я ж, навпаки, намагаюсь проілюструвати те, що, на мій погляд, назви торгових марок не слід перекладати, спробував вибрати найнеочікуваніше.)